# ZBar processor and delphi

Tags: delphi, zbar

Ok so I have been trying to get bar code scanning to work in a delphi application for the last 3 weeks now. Ive been directed to [this](http://blog.freehand.com.ua/2013/03/zbar-reading-bar-codes-in-delphi.html) example but that example uses other librarys like imagemagika and is a console application. I am looking for a vcl forms application.

Here is some code I have written to try and see if I can get the ZBar processor to work in delphi :

```
// Create Processor
processor := zbar_processor_create(0);
zbar_processor_set_config(processor, ZBAR_NONE, ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE, 1);

// Initialize processor
zbar_processor_init(processor, {what do I put here ?}, 1);

// Setup a callback
{I dont know what do here}

// Enable preview window
zbar_processor_set_visible(processor, 1);
zbar_processor_set_active(processor, 1);
```

This code is based on a example in C that I found here : https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/examples/processor.c

as well as the documentation over here :
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/api/zbar_8h.html#c-processor

The zbar window opens but it does not show the video feed because I parsed `nil` as a paramater in the initialize step. In the example they have this C code but I have no idea what it means :

```
const char *device = "/dev/video0";
 /* initialize the Processor */
if(argc > 1)
    device = argv[1];
zbar_processor_init(proc, device, 1);
```

If I parse `'/dev/video0'` instead of `nil` the video feed still doesn't show. So I guess my question is **what do I need to parse in `zbar_processor_init()` function ?**

I also dont know how to set up a callback function that will be called once a result is found. How would I go about doing this ?

Thanks in advance,
Kobus

Answer (score 2):

`argc` is the number of parameters passed in the command line and `argv` fetches them.  `dev/video` is linux style device.  Try `con:`

```
zbar_processor_init(processor, 'con:', 1)
```

`Con:` is the console.  `Com1:` serial port 1, `Aux:` auxiliary port - probably usb, `Prn:` the printer `Lpt:` the line printer.

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate please ? I am not sure what you mean by con: